# One-to-many relation ship between 3 entities in Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, model-associations

I have three entities: User, Office and PhoneNumber. The user has many phone numbers, and the office has many phone numbers too.

The problem is how to represent these entities relations in Doctrine 2.

1. At first I tried to use bi-directional one-to-many associations
   (User -> has many -> PhoneNumbers) (Office -> has many ->
   PhoneNumbers), the PhoneNumber has two mapping fields, one for User
   and anotherone for Office. This solution doesn't work since one of
   the mapping foreign keys couldn't be null.
2. My second approach was to use two entities and one superclass for PhoneNumber. The PhoneNumber superclass has defined all common fields except the mapping field. Entities UserPhoneNumber and
   OfficePhoneNumber extended the PhoneNumber entity and specified the
   different mapping field and different table. (one table for OfficePhoneNumbers, anotherone for UserPhoneNumbers)

   This solution actually works, but it is quite ugly to have 3
   classes to represent one simple entity.
3. My third approach is to use uni-directional one-to-many mapping. This will eliminate the need of mapping field for the PhoneNumber entity. The problem is that when I use cascade remove for the many-to-many field, it violates the integrity constraint when deleting records.

   When I omit the cascade remove option, after removing User or Office, the PhoneNumber remains in the Database (but the record in mapping table is removed).

What is the best way to handle this type of association?

Thanks

Comment: I've done solution 1) successfully before. Can you please elaborate more on your null constraint? Also, is every number unique? That plays a part too, i.e. can a phone number be both a user and office?

Comment: I don't remember the exact error message, since I rewrite my code to 3). I will try again solution 1) and let you know about the exact error message. Yes, every number is unique, user and office can't share the same number.

Comment: Just tried it. I created one office with 2 phone numbers and after trying to fetch it or delete it, I get this message: `Notice: Undefined index: office_id in D:\www\App\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php line 1270` office_id is mappedBy field of Phone.

Comment: Finally it works. I just make a stupid mistake and I specified join column name in mappedBy attribute, instead of field of Phone entity. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the problem connected with (probably the nicest) solution 1). The problem was in misunderstanding of mappedBy attribute which should specify the entity field, not the database field.